# Counting SQL queries in rails 2.3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm looking for a way to count the number of sql queries that occur for a given method call in a Rails 2.3.14 app, possibly using Rspec. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If this is an ad-hoc thing, you can always just have a look at `log/development.log` and see what comes up for your operation.

If you want more insight, you could always hack around inside the SQL logging subsystem and wrap around the method with `alias_method_chain` to capture whatever data you want. Never underestimate the power of a tactical monkeypatch! Be careful to do this only in your development environment, though, perhaps by framing your patch within a `if (Rails.env.development?)` conditional.

A good place to look is the `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter.log_info` method.

For monitoring your production environment you probably want to use a more advanced tool like  [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) to give you better reporting.